# Firebird SQL join returning unexpected values

Tags: sql, firebird

I'm trying to join two tables but it's returning multiples values where it shouldn't.

table utenvpro

```
numop  codref div1  div2 qtdenv dataenv     dataprevret
19997  110053  18    P     100  10/03/2015   16/03/2015  
19997  110053  18    M     98   10/03/2015   16/03/2015
19997  110053  18    G     100  10/03/2015   16/03/2015
19997  110053  149   P     100  10/03/2015   16/03/2015
19997  110053  149   M     99   10/03/2015   16/03/2015
19997  110053  149   G     97   10/03/2015   16/03/2015
19997  110053  1000  99    6    10/03/2015   16/03/2015
19997  110053  149   M     4    20/03/2015   25/03/2015
19997  110053  149   G     1    20/03/2015   25/03/2015
```

Table utretpro

```
numop codref div1 div2 qtdret dataret
19997  110053  18    P     100  17/03/2015
19997  110053  18    M     100  17/03/2015
19997  110053  18    G     100  17/03/2015
19997  110053  149   P     100  17/03/2015
19997  110053  149   M     100  17/03/2015
19997  110053  149   G     100  17/03/2015
```

query:

```
 select utenvpro.codred as Faccao, utenvpro.numop as OP,
     utenvpro.codref as Referencia, utenvpro.div1 as Cor,
     utenvpro.div2 as Tamanho, sum(utenvpro.qtdenv) as QTD_Enviada,
     utretpro.qtdret as QTD_Retorno, utenvpro.dataenv as Envio,
     utenvpro.dataprevret as Prev_Retorno, utretpro.dataret as Retorno
 from utenvpro 
left outer join utretpro on
         utenvpro.codemp=utretpro.codemp
         and utenvpro.codfor=utretpro.codfor
         and utenvpro.codcli=utretpro.codcli
         and utenvpro.numop=utretpro.numop
         and utenvpro.codref=utretpro.codref
         and utenvpro.div1=utretpro.div1
         and utenvpro.div2=utretpro.div2
where numop=19997
group by utenvpro.div2, utenvpro.codref, utenvpro.div1, utenvpro.codred,
     qtd_retorno, utenvpro.numop, utenvpro.dataenv,
     utenvpro.dataprevret, utretpro.dataret
order by op,referencia,envio,cor,tamanho
```

Result:

```
Faccao    OP    Referencia    Cor   Tamanho    Qtd_enviada QTD_retorno  envio    prev_retorno    retorno
3002    19997    110053       18       G          100        100    10/03/2015    16/03/2015    17/03/2015
3002    19997    110053       18       M          98         100    10/03/2015    16/03/2015    17/03/2015
3002    19997    110053       18       P          100        100    10/03/2015    16/03/2015    17/03/2015
3002    19997    110053       149      G          97         100    10/03/2015    16/03/2015    17/03/2015
3002    19997    110053       149      M          99         100    10/03/2015    16/03/2015    17/03/2015
3002    19997    110053       149      P          100        100    10/03/2015    16/03/2015    17/03/2015
3002    19997    110053       149      G          1          100    20/03/2015    25/03/2015    17/03/2015
3002    19997    110053       149      M          4          100    20/03/2015    25/03/2015    17/03/2015
```

I don't know if this is clear to understand but the last two rows from result shouldn't be displayed.

Comment: I know it's returning the two last rows from result because it is present on utenvpro table, but it's not present on utretpro table and I can't find a way to distinguish.

Comment: This is not very clear. You're referencing columns in your join and your GROUP BY that you didn't describe in your table data. Can you explain in words why you're expecting that the last two rows should be excluded?

Comment: Please be more specific in identifying the duplicates and describing why you think they shouldn't be included.

Comment: I didn't put the columns that appear on join but it exist on them, this table is large.

Comment: The utenvpro table are pieces that were sent and the utretpro table are pieces that returned. The codref parts = 110053 div1 = 1000 dvi2 = 99 return with another div1 and div2; if you look at utretpro table will see the last three rows of the table utenvpro are not present, because the last two lines of pieces sent have not yet returned, and the piece I Mentioned above was converted to others pieces.
The returned amount is 600 pieces but the result of the query is 800 pieces because of the last two lines that should not be included until it return.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understand what you want...

When you do a `left outer join`, you get all rows from the first table and matching rows from second.  If you want an intersection, use `inner join`.